# Learn programming for CnC lathes

Tags: functional-programming, network-programming, cnc

I would like to learn programming for CNC lathes.
First, what open-source programs (similar BobCAD-CAM) would be best?
Second, what is the best way to proceed in learning to use the programs?
I look forward to learning the answers to my questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good free CAD/CAM programs you can get off the net, just look on google. Personally, I recommend using Featurecam or Mastercam ( although neither are free, but they are good programs.)
As for learning to program, this website has a lot of useful information http://cnc-programming-by-gord.blogspot.com/2012_07_01_archive.html

I hope it helps you like it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Autodesk Fusion is free for hobby users. It allows you a full CAD/CAM package with loads of tutorials online and on Youtube. for simulation OpenSCAM will allow you to check on your code. Some of the fancier live tooling lathes have some machine specific stuff on them but in the end a solid knowledge of G-code will help decipher it.

Answer (score 0):

#1, you need to know which lathe & which controller you want to program. Then get the manuals for it. Some G & M codes are similar across many machines, but not all of them. So, get the proper programming manual for the exact machine.

#2, research the CAM software you want to learn. Are there certain shops you want to work at? Well then, what do they use? Research the most popular packages in your area. Figure that out & then learn the specific software. Otherwise, you're wasting your time.

Depending on what you pick, there are videos out there to give you a good idea of how they work. Re-sellers offer classes. Some websites have tutorials & manuals. Again, don't waste your time learning something you might not even use. Even after you pick something, the different versions of it have proven to be very different. So be sure you're learning the right software & the right version.